# Write to a REPL executable ran with mono in python?

Tags: python, mono, subprocess, stdin, popen

I running an [opensource executable](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1263927-win-mac-linux-minecraft-console-client-1-8-3) on a mac via [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/) from a python script ran from terminal.

Without the script, the interface is a command line. In attempt to programatically interface with the program, I set `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` to `PIPE` then I try to communicate. `stdout.readline()` works fine, but stalls on waiting for the last input which I may learn how to work with via threading. I don't know how to write to the terminal as an input to the program. I have used `stdin.write()` and `communicate()` and nothing works. I figured the problem may be specific to the project and, luckily, it is open source. I'm not sure how to use that to my advantage, though.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('mono MinecraftClient.exe ' + emailAddress + ' ' + passw + ' ' + ipAddress, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while(True):
        input = proc.stdout.readline()
        print input
        print proc.communicate(input + "\n")[0]
```

Comment: For what it's worth, communicate() will wait for process to return, so proc will actually be closed on the second pass through the loop and you're guaranteed an I/O error, so you do want stdin.write(). In general though, processing bidirectional stuff with a single-threaded loop is tricky because (just as one example) if your input doesn't result in any corresponding output, readline() will block indefinitely and you'll never get to do more input. That aside, I'm not sure what you're trying to do, since you seem to be taking the output of the program and passing it right back in as input.

Comment: @dahc I can give some background info on this since I am a friend of his. He is trying to have his python program read chat messages from Minecraft, and if it matches a condition, process the message and send back a response.

Tim, You might find it easier to use a Python-based client instead like [SpockBot](https://github.com/SpockBotMC/SpockBot) which I found in [this list](http://wiki.vg/Client_List).

Comment: It seems like a nice project. However, they attempt to install things in /usr/bin/ which is not editable in macs now.